# Deploying Wt application on domain

Tags: web, wt

maybe it's not a completely correct question, but I just need some direction to move in. I have my Wt app and I have a domain on domain.com. What is the best/easiest way to deploy my app on it? I tried to use Github Pages and of course, it requires HTML but Wt is kinda back-end + front-end already and it's an exe so I don't really know what to do. Also, I thought about just using something like WordPress but I'm not sure if I get the option to use the exe file or just only upload some HTML and css files.

Also, I tried to reach domain using my app by prescribing the address of my domain, but had errors like "failed to resolve address". Maybe I just need to write some DNS rules in the domain's properties? Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need a DNS A record pointing to the server running your Wt application. Wt should listen at port 80 (and/or 443 for HTTPS) or you should employ a reverse proxy.

I don't think you can host a Wt app using Github Pages or WordPress (although I'm not familiar with those services). Your best/cheapest option is to rent a VPS. Running your Wt application from your home/work network may be possible too, but is only recommended for test purpose or really small traffic.